# Grails 3.0.9 war deployment in external Tomcat 8 does not work

Tags: tomcat8, grails-3.0

I have built a grails application that works fine in grails. I would like to put it in "production" in a tomcat 8 webserver, and to do this I have read how it should be done [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#deployingAnApplication). Production Tomcat is running on Windows 7 and dev environment also.
After I have built the war-file(without the embedded tomcat) and put it in the web-apps directory in Tomcat it explodes fine. Checking tomcat manager(http://localhost:9080/manager/html) shows that the application is deployed and running.
However, when clicking on the link in tomcat manager I get the following stacktrace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.logThrowable(AbstractFilter.java:116)
    grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:73)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:184)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:167)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:131)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:190)
    grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:73)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:184)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:167)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:131)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
```

Does someone have an idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Ubuntu 14.04 / Tomcat 8

Can't say for sure what was the key to fixing the problem, I've done the following:

- Set provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat" in build.gradle
- Downloaded tomcat8 again (tar.gz package)
- Moved tomcat from /root to /opt

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited question, I am running windows. Already using the provided spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency. Thanks anyway for trying!